# I want an Amazon Product API to perform scraping, how can I get an Amazon Product API and use it to scrape the data?

Tags: web-scraping, aws-api-gateway

I have use different types of APIs such as Rainforest API, but it doesn't fulfill my needs to scrape all the required Amazon Product data.

So, can anyone tell me a way to get an official Amazon Product API, and perform the scraping on the same?

Comment: Have you found an alternative? I have been using rainforest-api for many years but lately they do not return correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to Rainforest is [Canopy](https://www.canopyapi.co/). It scrapes Amazon data and provides a GraphQL API for Amazon product data, search results, and categories.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the [Real-Time Amazon Data](https://rapidapi.com/letscrape-6bRBa3QguO5/api/real-time-amazon-data) which is an API we created when we didn't find an official Amazon API or alternatives which are highly-maintained and up-to-date.